# refresh a Jquery form wizard

Tags: jquery, html

I use this form wizard [LINK](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/GqXbl)

this form wizard is inside of a modal, i want to return to the first step if is close the modal, i can reset the form but i cant refresh it

this is my code to open it

```
$("#crear-orden").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    $("#myModal input[type='text']").val('');
    $("#myModal textarea").html('');          
});
```

and this is the code to try refresh/reload

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').load();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On close event of the window call:

```
$("#step-2").hide();
$("#step-3").hide();
$("#step-1").show();
```

Comment: what do you recommend me to remove class form the steps, i try to check if have a class with hasclass and alert but not show me the alert

Comment: jquery has a method called `removeClass` that you could use